# How can I reverse this text encoding?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, vb6

We have the encoding method below that accepts an input string from a legacy system file (in the Unicode format of a VB6 string) and the name of an encoding. It applies the encoding and returns a string that displays correctly in our newer web applications. As our newer applications have a reporting backend that still depends on the old formats I have a need to reverse the encoding to allow newly translated strings to be stored in the legacy files. Here are two examples of conversions done by the Encode method.

`Encode("µn¤J¦WºÙ", "BIG5")` returns **登入名稱**

`Encode("Çàðåãèñòðèðîâàííîå èìÿ", "windows-1251")` returns **Зарегистрированное имя**

To reverse these encodings I have been trying various encoding steps based on questions found here and elsewhere but have thus far succeeded only in producing output that appears identical to the input, is composed entirely of question marks or is composed of a mixture of ASCII characters and question marks different to the original input.

The encoding method was written by a departed colleague and I must admit that I don't fully understand why it has the coded loops, while all other examples I find simply get the characters from the string, then the bytes from those using the input encoding and finally get the string from the bytes using the output encoding. If I try removing the coded loops and just doing those three steps the method no longer returns the expected result.

Here is the encoding method, and my question is, how can I create a corresponding Decode method that reverses what it does?

```
    private static string Encode(string src, string encoding)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encoding)) return src;

        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
        Encoding sourceEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding);

        char[] srcChars = src.ToCharArray();
        byte[] srcBytes = sourceEncoding.GetBytes(srcChars);

        if (srcChars.Length == srcBytes.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < srcChars.Length; i++)
                if ((int)srcChars[i] < 256)
                    srcBytes[i] = (byte)srcChars[i];
        }
        else
        {
            srcBytes = new byte[srcChars.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < srcChars.Length; i++)
                srcBytes[i] = (byte)srcChars[i];
        }
        byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(sourceEncoding, unicode, srcBytes);

        return unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example string and encoding which you have not been able to encode and then reverse encode?

Comment: 8-bit encodings are lossy, you can never reliably recover the original bytes.  This kind of code is a hack around the real problem, this went wrong when the "src" string was read.  Fix *that* problem instead.